# How to continue running code after onPause

Tags: android

It's a bit weird question, but I have a handler (timer) running and if i lock my phone it pauses it. What I want to do is if I lock my phone the handler would continue running and execute the code after the desired time, even if the phone is locked. I'm fearly certain it has something to do with onPause() and onResume() methods.

Comment: You have to run a [background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks i seriously need to go through some of this documentation